# How to auto update versions in application.xml after maven release

Tags: java, xml, maven, ear, snapshot

application.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
  <description>DESCRIPTION</description>
  <display-name>xxxsystem-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <ejb>xxxsystem-ejb-3.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>xxxsystem-web-3.1.1-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/xxxsystem</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

After I run :
mvn release:clean
mvn release:prepare
mvn release:perform

So i have to change the versions of .jar and .war to 3.1.2 in xml file manually.

**There is a way to tell maven to change versions in this file for me?**

I have to do the same thing with jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>

    <sub-deployment name="xxx-ejb-3.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>

    <sub-deployment name="xxx-web-3.1.1-SNAPSHOT.war">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you manually writing the application.xml ? (I assume so..) why not letting the maven-ear-plugin generating the application.xml.

Comment: @khmarbaise worked, thanks for the help. Now i have to make the same thing with jboss-deployment-structure.xml do you know how to do this?

Comment: Why not setting the org.apache.log4j into scope **provided** into the different modules which should result in not packaging that file intot the resulting war, ear file.

Answer (score 6):

One good way to do this is to let maven take care of generating the application.xml file:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <version>6</version>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <modules>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xxxsystem-ejb</artifactId>
                    </ejbModule>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xxxsystem-web</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/xxxsystem</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Secondly, the jboss-deployment-structure.xml (assumed to be in src/main/application) can be generated with [filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/filtering-sources.html) enabled in the plugin (shown above) and it's source modified as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>

    <sub-deployment name="xxxsystem-ejb-${project.version}.jar">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>

    <sub-deployment name="xxxsystem-web-${project.version}.war">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Alternatively, you can generate the EAR with version-less embedded modules by [specifying the module filename](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/customizing-a-module-filename.html):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <version>6</version>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <modules>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xxxsystem-ejb</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>xxxsystem-ejb.jar</<bundleFileName>
                    </ejbModule>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xxxsystem-web</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>xxxsystem-web.war</<bundleFileName>
                        <contextRoot>/xxxsystem</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

in which case filter copying of the jboss-deployment-structure.xml is not required. Each sub-deployment-name would be matched with the `bundleFileName` used in the maven-ear-plugin configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Why Can You not use simply maven resource plugin?
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

If You configure the files correctly You need to use ${project.version} and its done